# Clarification in colnames function in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am new to R and I wanted to ask experts about the `colnames` function in `R`. Using the function I realized that it provides a `NULL` if used for single column of a matrix object, however it works perfectly fine for more than 1 columns of a matrix object. To illustrate, say I have  matrix `test`

```
 >test<-matrix(0,ncol=4,nrow=5)
 >colnames(test)<-c("A","B","C","D")
 >colnames(test[,1]) or colnames(test[,c(1)]) gives output as NULL
NULL
```

whereas the following works fine,

```
colnames(test[,c(1:2)])
[1] "A" "B"
```

I understand that alternative way is to use `colnames(test)[c(1:2)]`. Am I missing something here in the case where I am getting `NULL`.

Comment: `colnames(test[,1, drop=FALSE])`  will work. Take a look at `?"["`.

Comment: Try `test[,1]` Vs `test[,c(1:2)]` and you will understand

Comment: @Sotos thanks that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the description of `?colnames`. You'll see that it takes an argument `x` which is a `a matrix-like R object, with at least two dimensions for colnames.`

When you are calling `colnames(test[,1])` you are giving `colnames` a vector with 1 dimension. Compare `class(test[,1])` vs. `class(test[,c(1:2)])`. Vectors don't have columns or rows and therefore no column or row names. You can have named elements within a vector, but that is definitely not equivalent to the column names from a matrix

The best way to extract a single (or multiple) column name is to select the column after from the full vector of column names

```
colnames(test) # gives you all column names
colnames(test)[1] # gives you the column name 1
colnames(test)[c(1,2)] # gives you column names 1 and 2
```

Does this clarify this issue for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification...it really helped.